# Rotating screen on my laptop doesn't allow my mouse to go to lower portion of screen

Tags: windows-10, mouse, desktop

So, when I attempt to change my laptop's screen from landscape to portrait, the mouse doesn't go past the height of the landscape mode.

This is in landscape mode:
[image: landscape]
This is in portrait mode:
[image: portrait]

That red line is where the mouse stops.  At 1080.  Anyone know what's going on?  I haven't tried to reboot as that would defeat the reason why I'm doing this (testing an app), so I'm not going to go there.

```
Edition Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 20H2
Installed on    ‎2/‎7/‎2022
OS build    19042.1586
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0
```

Comment: What model is your display adapter and what is your video driver?

Comment: Voting to close this as a reboot likely fixes it. Why it doesn't work is nearly impossible to figure out. And its even possible that after a reboot in vertical orientation you can rotate both ways normally. Also the lack of info about what app you are testing is not helping either.

Comment: @harrymc, Windows show that it's a Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620.  The laptop is a Dell Latitude 7400.

Comment: Was @LPChip right and a reboot fixes this?

Comment: @harrymc, I'm debugging right now and have attached another couple of displays, so I have a workaround.  However, this is a problem when I'm working on the go.  I am skeptical that a reboot will fix this however, since if I were to rotate some of my other displays, I get some other weird problems with the mouse not moving above a certain point.  This may be related to my odd monitor setup where I have a landscape next to a  portrait, with my laptop below an to the right of the landscape.  When I get a chance, I'll try a reboot, but I'm not hopeful.

Comment: @LPChip, It is my job's app.  It's not relevant other than it needs to work is Landscape and Portrait modes.

Comment: You should at least reboot in the portrait orientation and tell us if it is fixed then, and if it stays fixed if you rotate again. Without this information its impossible to help you further.

Comment: Rebooting again in landscape mode didn't make a difference.  Rebooting in portrait mode seems to have cleared things up.  I've switched back and forth between P & L mode and it no longer seems to have the issue.  No idea.  Thx.

Comment: Seems to have cleared whatever was stuck.  Rebooting in landscape mode no longer has any issues swapping between L & P modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like restarting in portrait mode fixed what ever was stuck before.  It now has no issues with swapping between portrait and landscape modes no matter what mode I reboot in.